# Select last unique polymorphic objects ordered by created at in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to get unique polymorphic objects by the value of one of the columns. I'm using Postgres.

The object has the following properties: `id`, `available_type`, `available_id`, `value`, `created_at`, `updated_at`.

I'm looking to get the most recent object per `available_id` (recency determined by `created_at`) for records with the `available_type` of "User".

I've been trying ActiveRecord queries like this:

```
Service.where(available_type: "User").order(created_at: :desc).distinct(:available_id)
```

But it isn't limiting to one per `available_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Service.where(id: Service
              .where(available_type: "User")
              .group(:available_id)
              .maximum(:id).values)
```

Comment: It spawns 2 consecutive queries at any point of time, independent of number of records. Whereas, the other solution is clearly n+1...

Comment: This solution is not grabbing the most recent :created_at. Only the largest :id. In most cases they are the same thing, but just realize you might want to swap the :id with :created_at

Comment: And remember that this is using a subquery, which has its own inefficiencies. I've update my answer with a join operation that will usually be more performant than a subquery

Answer (score 1):

Using a left join is going to be your probably most efficient way

The following sql selects only rows where there are no rows with a larger created_at.

See this post for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27802817/5301717

```
query = <<-SQL
    SELECT m.*                    # get the row that contains the max value
    FROM services m                 # "m" from "max"
    LEFT JOIN services b        # "b" from "bigger"
        ON m.available_id = b.available_id    # match "max" row with "bigger" row by `home`
        AND m.available_type = b.available_type
        AND m.created_at < b.created_at    # want "bigger" than "max"
    WHERE b.created_at IS NULL      # keep only if there is no bigger than max
    AND service.available_type = 'User'
SQL

Service.find_by_sql(query)
```

distinct doesn't take a column name as an argument, only true/false.

distinct is for returning only distinct records and has nothing to do with filtering for a specific value.

if you need a specific `available_id`, you need to use `where`

e.g.

```
Service.distinct.where(available_type: "User").where(available_id: YOUR_ID_HERE).order(created_at: :desc)
```

to only get the most recent add `limit`

```
Service.distinct.where(available_type: "User").where(available_id: YOUR_ID_HERE).order(created_at: :desc).limit(1)
```

if you need to get the most recent of each distinct available_id, that will require a loop

first get the distinct polymorphic values by only selecting the columns that need to be distinct with `select`:

```
available_ids = Service.distinct.select(:available_id).where(available_type: 'User')
```

then get the most recent of each id:

```
recents = []
available_ids.each do |id|
  recents << Service.where(available_id: id).where(available_type: 'User').order(created_at: :desc).limit(1)
end
```

Comment: I don't need a specific `available_id`, I need one result per `available_id` (there are a handful of `available_ids`)

Comment: in that case you will need to limit your queried columns

Comment: Would the `.where(available_id: YOUR_ID_HERE)` you have still be used? I don't need results for one `available_id`, I'd like one result for each `available_id`.

Comment: it will but in a different way, see the last section of my answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How performant is this solution? Are there any other ones that might be better or more efficient?

Comment: This would be an O(n) operation on the rails side. It's possible, but it would take mostly pure sql as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @Andrew I added an sql solution that will be more efficient than a ruby loop